# Is there anyway to use multi-lingual text fields in Adobe Animate CC for HTML5 Canvas publishing?

Tags: javascript, html, createjs, easeljs, animate-cc

Animate CC 2017 by default doesn't support right to left languages for text inputs and labels, what is a right way for this issue? 
how to possible create new component for use in adobe animate for this?

Comment: I understand that asking right away is the easiest way, but maybe a minor effort prior to asking? Google > adobe flash text right to left

Comment: @Organis : A.M. is asking for **Adobe Animate**, not for Adobe Flash, these are totally different technologies. And BTW, asking Google leads to this page(!)... So, Adobe Animate uses EaselJS and it's Text class doesn't seem to allow right to left languages ([createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Text.html](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Text.html)), as its written on this page: _Note that as an alternative to Text, you can position HTML text above or below the canvas relative to items in the display list using the localToGlobal method, or using DOMElement._ That should be one solution.

Comment: @jck You are wrong so please undo whatever you are doing here, I quote: "Adobe Flash Professional is now Animate CC" https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/publish-multiple-platforms.html https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/actionscript.html

Comment: @Organis As you may now, Adobe Animate HTML5 Canvas is now the default publishing mode when you create a new document with the IDE. Flash and AS3 are still a possible option, but I presume that the author is asking about HTML5 Canvas and not about Flash, which is, as you now, a technology that will be soon deprecated. [https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html). To make it clear for everyone, I suggested an edit in the question to indicate 'HTML5 canvas publishing'.

Comment: @A.M. You wrote _Animate CC 2017 **by default** (...)_  Can you please confirm that the question is for **HTML5 Canvas publishing** and not for Flash publishing? As I know, Adobe Flash earlier versions of the IDE were allowing right to left writing with a text mode called 'TLF' (for Flash publishing). In the new versions of the IDE they removed this text mode option (both in Canvas HTML5, as it's not possible, and also for Flash publishing). Here you can see that this feature is still pending: [https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2133797](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2133797).

Comment: @Organis You quote: _"Adobe Flash Professional is now Animate CC"_, but you should know that Animate CC will stop Flash support in a near future (as soon as the Flash technology will be deprecated). That's one major reason why they changed the name of the software.

Comment: @jck I'm not here to holywar. A.M. tagged the problem as actionscript-3, we are not in the future, actionscript-3 is still supported. Yet if all of above does not ring a bell to you and you're positive that A.M. does not understand what he's doing, you are sure to proceed.